# Profile picture on the Stack Exchange profile is gray but not on Stack Overflow profile

Tags: bug, profile-picture

Why is my profile picture rendered like this?

[image]

But this is the picture I've uploaded:

[image]

This issue will render for Chrome, Edge and Firefox on Window 10.

[Here you could find my profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/5766114/h-pauwelyn)

Comment: Is that reproducible with _any browser_?

Comment: It isn't rendered like that for me and it sometimes happen that an incomplete image gets cached, Just wait for the cache to expire in 6 to 8 weeks ...

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: I've tried to use Chrome, Edge and Firefox and three times yes.

Comment: @rene: it's sinds I uploaded the images some months ago.

Comment: Just reupload, it happens. imgur fault, so nothing SE can do about it.

Comment: [inserts joke here about how the first image looks better]